# How to pass more than one input box values to a function defined in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass values of two input boxes to a single controller function.

```
   <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="regex" class="form-control" placeholder="Regex"
                       ng-model="do_parsing.data"
                       ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="text" name="modifier" class="form-control" placeholder="modifier">
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="input_data" rows="10" style="width: 555px; height: 214px"
                      placeholder="Insert your test string here"
                    ng-model="do_parsing.data"
                       ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <pre> <span ng-bind="do_parsing.data()"></span></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my `controller.js` file,

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var _data = '';
    $scope.do_parsing = {

        data: function(newData) {
            if (newData != undefined) {
                alert(newData);
            }
            return arguments.length ? (_data = newData) : _data;
        }
    };
});
```

I want to pass the values of first input box and the text area to `do_parsing` function and I want the function to return the parsed data to `pre` tag. That is, this `do_parsing` function should execute whenever the value of first input box, and the `text-area` changes. I have tried the above, but it reflects the same value in all the three places.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gody3k95/1/)

Comment: `do_parsing` is an **object** not a _function_. `do_parsing.data` is function, why is it bound as `ng-model` to `input` and `textarea`

Comment: so `data` is a function , right?no.. seems like a dictionary..

Comment: @Tushar sorry, I'm new to Angular..

Comment: you get same value, because you write all in **one** variable `_data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the input field and the textarea to some fields on the $scope object:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="regex" 
       class="form-control" placeholder="Regex"
       ng-model="inputValue"
       ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
```

and the textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" 
          id="input_data" 
          rows="10" 
          style="width: 555px; height: 214px"
          placeholder="Insert your test string here"
          ng-model="textareaValue"
          ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
</textarea>
```

and the resulting span to a function which will be called:

```
<pre>
    <span ng-bind="do_parsing.data()"></span>
</pre>
```

Now on your controller you could define this function:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.inputValue = '';
    $scope.textareaValue = '';

    $scope.do_parsing = {
        data: function() {
            // calculate some expression using the 2 values
            // which will be shown in the resulting span

            return $scope.inputValue + ' | ' + $scope.textareaValue; 
        }
    };
});
```

And here's a [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/21240/).

Comment: Hi, You don't even need to pass them as params to `do_parsing.data()`, you can access the textbox and textarea values by using the `$scope.inputValue` and ....

Comment: Very good point. I have updated my answer to reflect this remark.